# Django - How do I write a queryset that's equivalent to this SQL query? - Manging duplicates with Counting and FIRST_VALUE

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have Model "A" that both relates to another model and acts as a public face to the actual data (Model "B"), users can modify the contents of A but not of B.

For every B there can be many As, and they have a one to many relation.

When I display this model anytime there's two or more A's related to the B I see "duplicate" records with (almost always) the same data, a bad experience.

I want to return a queryset of A items that relate to the B items, and when there's more than one roll them up to the first entered item.

I also want to count the related model B items and return that count to give me an indication of how much duplication is available.

I wrote the following analogous SQL query which counts the related items and uses first_value to find the first A created partitioned by B.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT                         
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b_id) as count_related_items,
    FIRST_VALUE(id) OVER (PARTITION BY b_id order by created_time ASC) as first_filter,                       
    *
  FROM A 
) AS A1 
WHERE 
A1.first_filter = A1.id;
```

As requested, here's a simplified view of the models:

```
class CoreData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)    

class UserData(models.Model):

    core = models.ForeignKey("CoreData", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

When a user creates data it first checks/creates the CoreData, storing things like the title, and then it creates the UserData, with a reference to the CoreData.
When a second user creates a piece of data and it references the same CoreData is when the "duplication" is introduced and why you can roll up the UserData (in SQL) to find the count and the "first" entry in the one to many relation.

Comment: You could use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/  to run raw SQL in Django, 

If you need this to be a queryset, can you share the models as well? it would be super helpful

Comment: Certainly - and at the moment I implemented it as a raw query because that seemed sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming my understanding is correct -

If you are querying from the UserData model the query would look something like this:

Considering CoreData.id = 18

```
user_data = UserData.objects.filter(core__id=18).
order_by("created_time").annotate(duplicate_count=Count('core__userData', filter(core__id=18))).first()
```

***user_data*** would be the First object created which is related to the CoreData object. Also,

***user_data.duplicate_count*** will give you the Count of UserData objects that are related to the CoreData object.

Reference Docs on Annotate [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

**Update:**

If you need the list of UserData of specific CoreData you could use

```
user_data = UserData.objects.filter(core__id=18).
order_by("created_time").annotate(duplicate_count=Count('core__UserData', filter(core__id=18)))
```

Comment: Looks pretty close, but I think this would only return one row. I am looking for the entire list of UserData objects that align with the first created time for their respective core_id and the count of how many times they share a reference to other UserData objects which they will effectively be replacing in the output.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "UserData objects that align with the first created time for their respective core_id" : Is it like, The It would be a list of UserData which has the created time +/- 10 mins from CoreData.created_time ?

Comment: Sure - If you started with a list of all the CoreData items, and then looked up the UserData item which was the first created reference/relation. If you had a list of Fathers and you went and found their first Son and put them in their place.